# Smooth sub-orbifolds in the language of stacks

Tags: differential-topology, stacks, orbifolds

In most geometric categories, "monomorphism" is too general to describe useful notions of "embedding". This is the case e.g. [for schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19871/images-and-monomorphisms-of-schemes), complex manifolds, and differentiable manifolds.
So "embedding" needs some geometric input, not just abstract nonsense.

I was asking myself, for no particular reason, what is the correct notion of embedding in the case of differentiable orbifolds. I was expecting that, seeing an orbifold as a differentiable stack, it would be easy to cook up a natural definition by "lifting" it from the category of smooth manifolds.

Then google showed me [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.3303.pdf) paper, which uses the language of atlases, stating that there are "particular difficulties involving the notions of suborbifold and orbifold embedding", and "Unlike the case for manifolds, we also show that suborbifolds exist which are not the images of orbifold embeddings".

> **Q.1** Is there an intrinsic (i.e. language of stacks, no charts) definition of (closed) embedding of differentiable orbifolds* that generalizes the corresponding notion for smooth manifolds, and subsumes some of the most general notions of closed embedding (and of closed sub-orbifold ** ) that are considered reasonable by the orbifold community?

$^{*}$ I'd like to consider not necessarily effective orbifolds, i.e. the "generic stabilizer" doesn't need to be trivial.

$^{**}$ (since having a sub-thing that doesn't come from an embedding is ungodly).

---

Naively (without having read the literature) I would try as follows.

As an analogy, to define "closed substack" of an algebraic stack you need 
1) the definition of representable morphism of stacks
2) the fact that "closed embedding of schemes" is local on the target.

For a map $f:M\to N$ of differentiable manifolds TFAE:
1) $f(M)$ is a closed submanifold i.e. $f(M)$ is closed in $N$ and $N$ has an atlas adapted to the subset $f(M)$.
2) $f$ is an injective immersion (immersion meaning injective differential) which is a homeomorphism onto its image.
3) $f$ is a proper injective immersion.

I think 3) is local on the target, so we could use this.

So we could define the map of differentiable orbifolds $f:X\to Y$ to be an embedding if it is representable and for every $S\to Y$, with $S$ a manifold, the induced map $X\times_Y S\to S$ is an embedding of manifolds in the sense 3).

But wait...

The category of differentiable manifolds doesn't have all fiber products! So the above attempt doesn't even generalize embedding of manifolds. If I'm not mistaken, even an embedding of *manifolds* $X\to Y$ is not representable in general because the test map $S\to Y$ could be not transversal enough to $X$.

So I'm lead to ask:

> **Q.2** How to define representable morphisms of stacks when the base category doesn't have all the fiber products?

For orbifolds, maybe:

a) define $U\to Y$, with $U$ a manifold, to be a *submersion from a manifold* if, for every $S\to Y$ with $S$ a manifold, $S\times_Y U$ is a manifold and $S\times_Y U\to S$ is a submersion.

b) define $X\to Y$ *representable* if, for every submersion from a manifold $U\to Y$, $U\times_Y X$ is a manifold.

c) define $f:X\to Y$, with $X,Y$ orbifolds, to be an *embedding* if it is a proper injective immersion (once you have defined representability you have all local-on-the-target notions, and surjectivity can be defined essentially on points $X(\mathrm{pt})\to Y(\mathrm{pt})$).

> **Q.3** Does the above work? How does it compare with "orbifologists" definitions?

Comment: "How to define representable morphisms of stacks when the base category doesn't have all the fiber products?" Answer: you do it in exactly the same way as when the base category does have all fiber products, but you say "and the fiber product exists" every time you need to write down a fiber product.

Comment: @André Henriques: then is it correct that an embedding of manifolds will not be representable, in general, according to this definition?

Comment: For c) do you really mean a proper _surjective_ submersion? Between manifolds, these are fibre bundle projections.

Comment: @David Roberts: Oh no, I meant proper *injective immersion*, like in point 3). Thanks for catching it; corrected.

Comment: So here's a rhetorical question: given finite $G < SO(n)$ and the resulting orbifold $\mathbb{R}^n/G$, if $H<G$, is $\mathbb{R}^n/H$ considered a suborbifold? Or, worse, $\{0\}/H$?

Comment: Well, $\mathbb{R}^n/H$ should probably not be considered a suborbifold of $\mathbb{R}^n/G$ in general: e.g. for $H=1$ and $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ acting by $x\mapsto -x$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, the restriction to the complements of the origin is not even injective.

Comment: As for whether $BH\to BG$ is an "embedding", maybe it "should" be. But I think, according to my attempt of definition, it is not. $*\to BG$ is a surjection from a manifold ($S\times_{BG} *$ is a principal $G$-bundle over $S$); Any $U\to BG$ factors as $U\to * \to BG$, and $*\times_{BG} BH\simeq G/H$ so $BH\to BG$ is representable. But $G/H\to *$ is definitely not an embedding of manifolds.... Any ideas? BTW what is your rhetorical answer to your rhetorical question?

Comment: This is correct: an embedding of manifolds is not a representable morphism. A representable morphism $A \to B$, with typical fiber $F$, corresponds, intuitively, to the notion of a family of $F$'s parametrised by the points of $B$.

Comment: @Qfwfq what if $H$ is a subgroup that acts trivially? Since you are allowing ineffective orbifolds... (And, no, I don't know the answer. I'd also like to know the answer to your original question, which I think would address my rhetorical one)

Comment: @David Roberts: which example do you have in mind? In both my previous examples $H$ was acting trivially. -- Anyway, I think I had a preconception: I thought that when $X\to Y$ is a faithful inclusion of (fibered) categories *and* $X$ and $Y$ are stacks over "coarse moduli spaces" $X',Y'$  which are manifolds (e.g. in the case of certain gerbes) *and* the map $X'\to Y'$ is an embedding, then the map $X\to Y$ had to be itself an embedding. But the above example of $BH\to BG$, for $H<G$, seems to show that it is not the case. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Even when $X\to Y$ is a closed embedding on each "level" of the geometric groupoids, the (homotopy/stacky) fibers can very well be non trivial (e.g. $\simeq G/H$). And it seems reasonable to me that an "embedding" should at least have "trivial" fibers. So the $X\to Y$, for an "embedding", has probably to be (categorially) faithful?

Comment: @Qfwfq my understanding is that substacks correspond to full subcategories, but I can't guarantee the more classical orbifold literature allows for something more general. (no particular example in mind...)

Comment: Yeah, indeed in the last phrase of my previous comment I actually meant "full", not "faithful" (I can't edit).